# In continue of questions "DB Schema for storing tagged records" -- how to select list of items with tags?

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql, optimization

Good day!

There are a lot of questions how to store tags in DB here on stackoverflow, I finally decide to use Toxi approach (items table, tags table and many-to-many intermediate table) http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/04/tags-database-schemas.html

I want to display a list of 20-50 tagged items on a page each with list of it's tags (I use LINQ2SQL in ASP.NET 3.5).

I see some options:

1. First query for list of items than run query for each item to select tags for each item -- seems to be slow, but caching on application level can improve situation.
2. Denormalize items table and store list of tags for item in text field in "items" table.

However both options seem bad to me, may be I'm missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2KLE: thanks, I got it. The result of this query is one row for each tags (Item data is duplicated), so anyway there is need to process resultset in application code. Am I right?

For LINQ 2 SQL I used DataLoadOptions to specify what associated data I want to load. Here is an example of code generated by LINQ2SQL to select all items with all tags.

Please note that Items table is called Snippets in my example (so we have Snippets, Tags and SnippetsTags tables). Another thing to note is that LINQ2SQL doesn't support Many-To-Many relations out of the box, so there is an entity class for intermediate table (SnippetsTag). Here are C# code:

```
            using (SnippetsDataContext context = UtilsLinq.CreateContext())
        {
            DataLoadOptions dl = new DataLoadOptions();
            dl.LoadWith<Snippet>(s => s.SnippetsTags);
            dl.LoadWith<SnippetsTag>(st => st.Tag);
            context.LoadOptions = dl;
            var result = (from s in context.Snippets
                          select s).ToList();

            string x = result.First().SnippetsTags.First().Tag.Title;
        }
```

Here is a SQL which LINQ to SQL generates:

```
    SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[Title], [t0].[Text], [t0].[Created], [t1].[Id] AS [Id2], [t1].[TagId], [t1].[SnippetId], [t2].[Id] AS [Id3], [t2].[Title] AS [Title2], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [dbo].[SnippetsTags] AS [t3]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Tags] AS [t4] ON [t4].[Id] = [t3].[TagId]
    WHERE [t3].[SnippetId] = [t0].[Id]
    ) AS [value]
FROM [dbo].[Snippets] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN ([dbo].[SnippetsTags] AS [t1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Tags] AS [t2] ON [t2].[Id] = [t1].[TagId]) ON [t1].[SnippetId] = [t0].[Id]
ORDER BY [t0].[Id], [t1].[Id], [t2].[Id]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend Option #2 because it will overcomplicate attempts to isolate a tag or group of tags.  My recommendation would be to leave the data model as is (`ITEMS`, `TAGS`, `ITEM_TAGS_XREF`), and query against a VIEW  which would contain a computed column containing the list of tags.  If you mentioned what database you're using, we can provide the query that will construct a comma/etc delimited string of the tags an item is associated with.

Assuming primary and foreign keys are setup accordingly, the performance shouldn't be bad - is it possible the lag is occurring in the application layer?

Comment: Thanks for detailed response! Can you share an pseudo code for this view? Should computed column perform corelated subquery for each row over tags table? Is it acceptable in terms of performance?

Thanks!

Comment: What database are you using?  I'm not familiar with LINQ.  I'm sure the query could be constructed to use a JOIN rather than correlated query.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly ...

Maybe you could create a query that joins all three table. In only one fast query, you would get all information... In SQL, it could be something like:

```
    select ... //itemColumns, tagColumns
    from item
    join tagItem on item.id = tagItem.itemId
    join tag on tag.id = tagItem.tagId
    where ... // your other conditions
```